# Why is the divergence of $v=\frac{1}{r^2} \hat{r}$ zero everywhere (except the origin)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Manipulating the equations, I understand how to get $0$, but is there a more intuitive/physical explanation? Moreover, why isn't the behavior of the divergence of $\frac{1}{r^2}\hat{r}$ the same as say, $\frac{1}{r}\hat{r}$ or $r^2$?

Comment: Do you know the intuitive/physical explanation of *divergence*? (http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~karigian)/teaching/multivariable-calculus/curldiv.pdf

Comment: Could you please repost the link? It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: 2nd try: http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~karigian/teaching/multivariable-calculus/curldiv.pdf

Comment: And $r^2$ is a *scalar* field...

Answer (score 1):

1. The flux of $v$ across the sphere $|x|=r$ is equal to $(4\pi r^2 )( r^{-2}) = 4\pi$, i.e., is independent of $R$. It follows that the integral of divergence over every spherical shell $R_1<|x|<R_2$ is zero.
2. Since the field is rotationally invariant, so it its divergence: that is, the divergence  depends on $|x|$ only.
3. Putting 1 and 2 together, we can conclude that the divergence is identically zero, except  possibly at the origin. At the origin we have the point source of intensity $4\pi$.
4. The above only works because $r^{-2}$ cancels $r^2$ in the formula for the area  of a sphere. Any other exponent would not cancel out, leading the the flux being dependent on $r$ and consequently the divergence being nonzero.
5. Generalization: in $n$ dimensions,  $r^{1-n}\hat r$ has the above properties.

Answer (score 0):

In Electrostatic, $\hat{r}/r^{2}$ is the electric field produced by a charge $+1$ at the origin of coordinates. The charge density associated to that charge is represented by a 
[Dirac Delta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). Namely, $\delta\left(\vec{r}\right) = \nabla\cdot\left[\left(\hat{r}/r^{2}\right)/\left(4\pi\right)\right]$.